# When text is entered correctly, image lights up/changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a section on my website for language learning. The user will see the word   でんき (Japanese word).   When someone enters in the correct text that matches each symbol, one of them will light up.  How could I achieve this?

Here is a preview image of my site: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/hiraganaquiz2.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
<span data-value="Car">{character that means Car}</span>
<span data-value="Boat">{character that means Boat}</span>
<span data-value="Plane">{character that means Plane}</span>
<input>
```

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('[data-value]').removeClass('highlight');
    $('[data-value="'+val+'"]').addClass('highlight');
});
```

Explanation:

The `data-value` will hold the English text of your character. When the user types a value that matches it, it will add the `highlight` class to all elements that have a `data-value` matching the text. Just apply your "lighting up" styles to the class.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MTVtM/

To work with multiple words just `split` the value by a space and check each piece:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('[data-value]').removeClass('highlight');
    val.split(' ').forEach(function(v) {
      $('[data-value="'+v+'"]').addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MTVtM/1/ (Try entering "Car Boat")

Comment: Here is preview of my design. 
http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/webapp/hiraganaquiz2.jpg

 Is it possible instead of text to highlight, to have one of the "images" of the symbols of the Japanese characters change to red like I have on the first one? like a roll over?

Comment: I get "error 403" with your link, but yes you can just use `.highlight{color:red}` Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MTVtM/3/

Comment: Thanks Madmartigan! Try pasting the link in your browser, it doesnt seem to be working when clicked.. not sure why.  My problem is that i want the image to change, instead of working with just text.  Is that possible? I am going to create the highlight on a separate image so the design looks better. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with a normal input field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var answer = 'foo';
function checkMatch(val) {
    if (val == answer) {
        alert('CORRECT!');
    }
}
</script>


<input type="text" id="word_box" value="" onkeyup="checkMatch(this.value)" />
```

This is incredibly simplified, but you get the idea. onkeyup will be called whenever a key is pressed in a box or other editable field.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="question">
    <span data-answer="correctAnswerOne">で</span>
    <span data-answer="correctAnswerTwo">ん</span>
    <span data-answer="correctAnswerThree">き</span>
<div>
<label for="answer">Enter your Answer</label>
<input id="answer" />
```

Javascript

```
//Build an array of correct answers
var answerArray = "";
var i = 0;
$('.question span').each( function() {
    answerArray[i] = this.attr('data-answer');
    i++;
} );

//On key up, get user input
$('input').keyup(function(){
    $('.question span').removeClass('highlight');
    var userInput = $('#inputElementID');
    var userInputArray = string.split(' ');//Split the string into an array based on spaces (I assume you are looking for three separate words
    var answerCount = array.length;
    for (i=0;answerCount >= i;i=i+1) {
        if (userInputArray[i] == answerArray[i]) {
            $('span[data-answer=' + answerArray[i] + ']').addClass('highlight');
        }
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.highlight{
    background-color:yellow;   
}
```

Comment: This looks great so far! Matthew, Thanks! How would I go about having it where for instance, someone enters "de" in the text field and having one of the Japanese characters light up, letting the user know that are right so far? Thank you!

Comment: Updated example to be more complete. Should answer your question.

Comment: Here is preview of my design. 
http://www.japanesefriend.zxq.net/webapp/hiraganaquiz2.jpg
 Is it possible instead of text to highlight, to have one of the "images" of the symbols of the Japanese characters change to red like I have on the first one? like a roll over?

Comment: In my example, I am just adding a class to the span with the image. This could easily be used to change a background position on a background image or something along those lines to swap the white image with the red one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one to add to the mix. Short answer is use Javascript, HTML, and CSS to accomplish this.

http://jsfiddle.net/BUxvx/1/

HTML

```
<span data-answer="cat" data-for="1">Symbol 1</span>
<span data-answer="dog" data-for="2">Symbol 2</span>
<span data-answer="chicken" data-for="3">Symbol 3</span>
<br />
<input type="text" data-for="1" />
<input type="text" data-for="2" />
<input type="text" data-for="3" />
< - Type answers here
<br />
<span>cat</span>
<span>dog</span>
<span>chicken</span>​
```

JavaScript

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    $txt = $(this); 
    $span = $('span[data-for="' + $txt.attr('data-for') + '"]'); 
    if($(this).val() === $span.attr('data-answer')){
        $span.addClass('highlight'); 
    }else{
        $span.removeClass('highlight');        
    }
}); ​
```

CSS

```
span{
 display:inline-block;
 height:75px; 
 width:75px;   
 line-height:75px;
 text-align:center;
 border:1px solid black;    
}

input{
 width:75px;    
 border:1px solid black; 
}
.highlight{
 background-color:yellow;   
}
​
```

Comment: OK, these are great! I understand the code perfectly.  My last question would be, instead of text just highlighting, could I have the image change when the text entered correctly? Im designing in Photoshop, so I want things to look very nice with good graphics.  Thanks again guys!

Comment: Here is preview of my design. 
http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/webapp/hiraganaquiz2.jpg

 Is it possible instead of text to highlight, to have one of the "images" of the symbols of the Japanese characters change to red like I have on the first one? like a roll over?

Comment: @AnthonyPinskey - I couldn't access your site. I was getting an access denied error, but I think this may represent what you're looking for (It may need some adjustment). http://jsfiddle.net/BUxvx/2/